# Flutter regular expressions

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

Im struggling with regular expressions. Here I have an example !

```
  RegExp  timeExp = RegExp(r"^[0-9]{1,2}?:[0-9]{0,2}");

  String time1 = "12"; // should be valid
  String time2 = "12:30"; // should be valid
  String time3 = "123:20:"; // should be valid
  String time4 = "123::20:"; // should NOT be valid
  String time5 = "12::20:"; // should NOT be valid
  String time5 = "1:20:"; // should be valid

   if(timeExp.hasMatch(time1)){
    print('time1 is valid');
   }

   if(timeExp.hasMatch(time2)){
    print('time2 is valid');
   }

  if(timeExp.hasMatch(time3)){
    print('time3 is valid');
   }

  if(timeExp.hasMatch(time4)){
   print('time4 is valid');
  }

  if(timeExp.hasMatch(time5)){
   print('time5 is valid');
  }
```

The regular expression is not working properly.
Could somebody help ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
^[0-9]{1,3}(?::[0-9]{1,3})*:?$
```

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0eg8k/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `[0-9]{1,3}` - one, two or three digits
- `(?::[0-9]{1,3})*` - zero or more occurrences of a `:` and one, two or three digits
- `:?` - an optional `:`
- `$` - end of string.

Another possible solution is

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?::|$))+$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0eg8k/2), where `(?:[0-9]{1,3}(?::|$))+` matches one or more occurrences of one to three digits followed with either `:` or `$`.

If you need to match any amount of digits in the digit part, replace `{1,3}` with `+`.

Comment: Sorry, an error crept in. At time3 should be 123:20. So I fixed that ^[0-9]{1,3}(?::[0-9]{1,3})?$, but then I have the problem, that I can't deleted the whole string, because 123: is not allowed. Is there a possible way to fix that ?

Comment: @LazyTurtle I have just checked several times, and even with `123:20`, both regexps above work. Can you please share a regex fiddle showing the issue you are having? Do you mean `123:20:` and `1:20:`  must be INVALID and you meant to say `123:20`  and `1:20` are valid, with no `:` at the end? Then you need `^[0-9]{1,3}(?::[0-9]{0,3})?$`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f0eg8k/3).

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/3sxdtb/2
The second one has to be possible. The fourth not.

Comment: @LazyTurtle Yes, `^[0-9]{1,3}(?::[0-9]{0,3})?$` will work.

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples, please try following regex.

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3})(?::[0-9]{1,3}[:]?)?$
```

[Online demo for above regex](https://regex101.com/r/V9AvLJ/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above regex.

```
^(?:[0-9]{1,3})  ##Matching from starting of value in a non-capturing group 1 to 3 digits here.
(?:              ##Starting another non-capturing group from here.
  :[0-9]{1,3}    ##Matching colon followed by 1 to 3 occurrences of digits here.
  [:]?           ##Matching 0 or 1 colon occurrences here.
)?$              ##Keeping this non-capturing group as optional at end of value.
```